# bootstrap dropdown menu link not working

Tags: php, html

I have figured out the answer, what was happening is that I had added classes inside the , so there were elements overlapping my link, leaving me unable to click on it. Thank you for all your help!

I'd like to edit what I have said below. I have changed the link to https://www.google.com/, and when I click it, it does nothing. I believe my problem has to do with the href being within the link

I have a php page. I want to link to from my html page. The link is within a dropdown menu, which I got from bootstrap. When I hover over my link, my cursor turns into the hand. But on clicking it is not going to the page. I can't figure out how to fix this issue for the life of me.

Here is the code:

```
<li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Classes<b class="caret"></b></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
             <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="https://127.0.0.7/IA/Student side/PHP/\PHP\IB comp sci\main_login.php" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">IB Comp Sci</a>        
          <a href="IA/Student side/PHP/web design/main_login.php" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Web Design</a>
          <a href="https://127.0.0.7/IA/Student%20side/PHP/web%20design/Computer%20repair%20 one\main_login.php" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Comp Repair 1</a>
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Comp Repair 2</a>
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Comp Warrior Tech</a>
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Digital Tools</a>
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Personal Finance</a>
        </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
```

I think that it either has to do with the fact that the links are inside a list, or that they are redirecting to a php page. The link won't work when I click it, however if I inspect the element and click the link it bring me to the correct page.

Comment: that is because the hand is the default for `a`

Comment: ```\``` and `/` have different meanings in URLs.

Comment: have you tried repalcing spaces with %20 and using / for \. 
In `https://127.0.0.7/IA/Student%20side/PHP/web%20design/Computer%20repair%20 one/main_login.php` there is a space between `%20` and `one\main_page.php`

Answer (score 0):

In your style use this code

```
style="cursor:default"
```

Eg

```
 <a href="" style="cursor:default">Test</a>
```

Comment: What would that do other than change the way the cursor looks? I want it to show up as the hand, however the link won't work when I click it, however if I inspect the element and click the link it bring me to the correct page.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is exists in your style of making links, As @Gumbo says You have mixed the \ and / in your links. Remember separation of folders must be done by / in http/https links. While \ only used for escaping. Also used only one style of making links, Don't just pick up the link from any url and placed on your anchor tag. I would suggest to not to use any of \ as browser automatically handle this.

```
 <a href="https://127.0.0.7/IA/Student side/PHP/PHP IB comp sci/main_login.php" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">IB Comp Sci</a>        
 <a href="https://127.0.0.7/IA/Student side/PHP/web design/main_login.php" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Web Design</a>
 <a href="https://127.0.0.7/IA/Student side/PHP/web design/Computer repair one/main_login.php" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Comp Repair 1</a>
```

Comment: Ok, but my problem with avoiding the spaces (for this project) is that these urls are already spread throughout my webpages, and I don't have enough time to finish them. These links are the only things keeping this project from being finished

Comment: I could just type %20 instead of the space, correct?

Comment: Well %20 and spaced urls both will work in urls, I just saying it is good for uniformity and also less confusing. Main problem is using \ and / not accordingly, As you clearly can see that I removed all \ in urls, While converting folder boundaries with / . It works because http url allow / as folder boundary not \.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on exactly what link you are trying to get to work, take the following into consideration.

Links containging only a "#" will link to that part of the current page, such as an anchor or an element with a ID. This will not navigate away from the page or reload the page in most cases.

As for your link to your website files, you have very add formatting for the URL with forward and backward slashes. Remove the backward slashes (\) since they don't change directories such as forward slashes (/)

```
<a href="https://127.0.0.7/IA/Student side/PHP/PHP/IB comp sci/main_login.php" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">IB Comp Sci</a>       
<a href="https://127.0.0.7/IA/Student side/PHP/web design/main_login.php" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Web Design</a>
<a href="https://127.0.0.7/IA/Student%20side/PHP/web%20design/Computer%20repair%20 one/main_login.php" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Comp Repair 1</a>
```

As for having spaces in a URL, try to avoid them, along with any other symbols other than "-" and "_", but those should also try to be avoided if possible. Also try to keep everything formatted to lowercase, since URL's are case sensitive.